# Run Mythril tool on a Hardhat Project?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, cross-compiling, smartcontracts, hardhat

How to run the Mythril tool for analysis on smart contracts compiled by Hardhat?

1. Hardhat project has the contract(.sol) and artifacts(.json) files .
2. Mythril when run with a (.sol) contract uses solc-compiler to compile the contract, whereas solc-compiler does not work for me, and I want to **use hardhat to compile and later Mythril to analyze it.**

*Research-Based*